# Start a private Message to previously unkown user with Azure Web App Bot

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots, proactive

I want to build a Notification System inside Microsoft Teams with a Web App Bot which should send notifcations to our employees. It should also work for users  who never came in contact with my bot before.

The [examples from Micrsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) shows the concept of proactive Messages but if i understand it correctly it always needs the user to start the initial conversation.

Is there any way to contact a user without this initial conversation? Maybe with using the Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to message a user, you must have a conversation reference.  If the user has not interacted with the bot previously the bot will not have the conversation reference to proactively send a message.

This is a feature by design to prevent spambots.  I understand your use case is messaging people within your organization, but this is not a supported scenario.